# allowing options method with restify - Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I'm writing a nodejs api application using restify framework.

I'm enabling cors for cross domain access.

restify is configured with the following code:

```
var restify = require('restify'),
fs = require('fs');

var server = restify.createServer({
  certificate: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/keys/myalcoholist/server.crt'),
key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/keys/myalcoholist/server.key'),
name: 'MyAlcoholist',
});
function corsHandler(req, res, next) {

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Api-Version, X-Request-Id, X-Response-Time');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');

return next();
}
function optionsRoute(req, res, next) {

res.send(200);
return next();
}



server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS({
origins: ['http://127.0.0.1', 'https://myalcoholist.com', 'https://www.myalcoholist.com'],   // defaults to ['*']
credentials: true,                 // defaults to false
headers: ['x-foo'],                 // sets expose-headers
methods: ['GET','PUT','DELETE','POST','OPTIONS']
}));

server.opts('/\.*/', corsHandler, optionsRoute);

server.listen(8888, function() {
console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

as you can see I implemented a `corsHandler` function to handle OPTIONS request. the problem is that I'm having is that when I'm accessing this nodejs api from https://myalcoholist.com I get the following error in my google chrome browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myalcoholist.com:8888/cocktail/get_latest_drinks. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

any ideas why I get this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Restify has removed CORS support directly, and this is now handled by a plugin, [restify-cors-middleware](https://github.com/Tabcorp/restify-cors-middleware).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the answer it's pretty simple, I need to add `Authorization` to the allowed headers. so my corsHandler function that works is the following:

```
function corsHandler(req, res, next) {

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Api-Version, X-Request-Id, X-Response-Time');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');

return next();
}
```

Comment: Works very well

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve restify issues of OPTIONS MethodNotAllowed error and CORS preflight issue with GET/POST by the following

```js
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: "Test Server",
    version: "2.0.1"
});

function corsHandler(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Api-Version, X-Request-Id, X-Response-Time');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');
    return next();
}

function optionsRoute(req, res, next) {
    res.send(200);
    return next();
}

server.use(restify.CORS({
credentials: true,                 // defaults to false
methods: ['GET','PUT','DELETE','POST','OPTIONS']
}));

/*
routes and authentication handlers 
*/

server.opts('/\.*/', corsHandler, optionsRoute);
server.listen(serverPort, function() {
    var consoleMessage = '\n Test Server';
}
```